# Probability of Losing a Dice Game

Tags: probability, game-theory, dice

Consider the following game.

> A game involves rolling two six-sided dice, followed by rolling a
> third six-sided die. To win the game, the number rolled on the third
> die must lie between the two numbers rolled previously. For example,
> if the first two dice show $1$ and $4$, the game can only be won by
> rolling a  $2$ or $3$ with the third die.

I am trying to find the **probability that a player has no chance of winning before rolling the third die**.

My thought process was that this only occurs when the first two rolls are the same number or consecutive numbers. Both of these have probability $1/6$ and so the probability of losing before the third roll is $1/6+1/6=1/3$.

However, the solution states the probability is $4/9$. I do not understand how my logic is incorrect.

Comment: The probability of the first two rolls being consecutive numbers isn't $1/6$.  You could roll $12$, $23$, $34$, $45$, or $56$, in either order, for a total of $10$ possibilities, and a probability of $10/36=5/18$.  (Otherwise, your reasoning is correct.)

Comment: Silly question, but if we can roll $12, 23, 34, 45$ or $56$ in any order, why do we not have $12$ possibilities of rolling the same number (i.e. while $11$ is the same as $11$, can we not distinguish these)?

Comment: As in your comment, you can roll 12, 23, 34, 45, 56 or their reversed orders, which are just $10$ possibilities out of $36$.

Comment: Right... 11 is the same as 11, we can't distinguish those (because they're identical).  Another way to see this: after the first roll, whatever it is, there's only one possibility for the second roll that makes the two rolls identical (probability is $1/6$).  There's either one possibility ($1/3$ of the time) or two ($2/3$ of the time) for the second roll that makes the two rolls consecutive (probability is $1/18 + 4/18 = 5/18$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice the probability of having consecutive numbers is actually $\dfrac{4}{9}$. In this case, the first two dice rolls are distinct, so we have $5 \cdot 2$ ways for the two dice out of $36$ total was. We get $5 \cdot 2$ because we have $(1, 2), (2, 3), \dots, (5, 6)$ and the same thing with the ordered pairs reversed. From $\dfrac{5}{18} + \dfrac{1}{6}$, the answer is $\dfrac{4}{9}$ as your solution states

Hope this helps your understanding!

Answer (score 1):

Probability of having the same number is $\frac16$ however to have consecutive numbers the probability is $\frac5{18}$ which sums to $\frac49$

Comment: Why is the probability $5/18$ and not $5/36$? Have you assumed that the roll $1$ and $2$ is different from the roll $2$ and $1$?

Answer (score 0):

Simple, you’re being asked the probability of the second dice being equal in value to the first having having a difference in value of one. If the first die is 2,3,4 or 5, the the probability is clearly $3/6=1/2.$ However if the first result is 1 or 6, then the probability is $2/6=1/3$. And finally $2/3*1/2+1/3*1/3=4/9$.